# $\big\|\sum_{j\in J}A_j^*LA_j\big\|\le \big\|\sum_{j\in J}A_j^*A_j\big\|\ \|L\|?,\;\forall \,L\in \mathcal{L}(H)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

Given a finite family $A:=(A_j)_{j\in J}$ of operators $A_j \in\mathcal{L}(H)$,

> It is true that for all $L\in \mathcal{L}(H)$, we have
>   $$\big\|\sum_{j\in J}A_j^*LA_j\big\|\le \big\|\sum_{j\in J}A_j^*A_j\big\|\ \|L\|?$$

If $L\in \mathcal{L}(H)^+$, one has
$$\big\|\sum_{j\in J}A_j^*LA_j\big\|\le \big\|\sum_{j\in J}A_j^*A_j\big\|\ \|L\|.$$
 Indeed, for any $x\in H$, 
$$ \big(\sum_{j\in J}A_j^*LA_jx, \ x\big) =  \sum_{j\in J}(A_j^*LA_jx,x) =  \sum_{j\in J}(LA_jx,A_jx)\le   \sum_{j\in J}\|L\|(A_jx,A_jx)$$
$$=  \|L\| \sum_{j\in J}(A_j^*A_jx,x)\le\|L\|\ \big\|\sum_{j\in J}A_j^*A_j\big\|\ \|x\|^2.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually yes: it follows from the analogous inequality for any $x$ and $y$, and Cauchy-Schwarz. One has

$$ \big(\sum_{j\in J}A_j^*LA_jx, \ y\big) =  \sum_{j\in J}(A_j^*LA_jx,y) =  \sum_{j\in J}(LA_jx,A_jy)\le   \sum_{j\in J}\|L\|\ \|A_jx\|\|A_jy\|$$
$$ \le\|L\|\sqrt{ \sum_{j\in J}\|A_jx\|^2 \sum_{j\in J}\|A_jy\|^2 }
=\|L\|\sqrt{ \sum_{j\in J}(A_j^*A_jx,x) \sum_{j\in J}(A_j^*A_jy,y) }
$$

$$\le\|L\|\ \big\|\sum_{j\in J}A_j^*A_j\big\|\ \|x\|\|y\|.$$